# jquery to set the property selected to selected of a dropdownlist

Tags: php

i need to set the selected property of a dynamically generated dropdown to a value that matches with the id of a record selected from the database.
below is the jquery which generates the dropdown dynamically,

```
function cityBind(obj)
{
    var dropDown = "<b>Preferred Location <sup><font color='Red' >*</font> : </b><select name='city' id='city'><option value='' >Select City</option>";
    for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++)
        {
            dropDown = dropDown+"<option value='"+obj[i].id+"'  >"+obj[i].city+"</option>";
        }
    dropDown = dropDown+"</select>";
    $("#citydiv").html(dropDown);
}
```

i am a beginner and i am looking for a help on this from experts.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Oveflow. Please visit the help center and take the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) to see what to ask and how.

Comment: Paste your code and press ctrl+K in editor, you missed part of for loop syntax and code.

Answer (score 0):

```
for(var i=0; i<obj.length; i++)
    {   
        if($("#cityid").val() == obj[i].id)
            dropDown = dropDown+"<option value='"+obj[i].id+"' selected=selected >"+obj[i].city+"</option>";
        else
            dropDown = dropDown+"<option value='"+obj[i].id+"'  >"+obj[i].city+"</option>";
    }
```

just made little change in code and solved the problem, thaks all.